# “Would” in a reported statement

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, tenses, indirect-speech

I am teaching some students changing original quotes into reported speech. Well, one of my students asked how the following quote can be changed into reported speech:

> I would like to swim.

From my understanding, "would like to" simply means "want to". So, the whole sentence is a "present tense", am I right?

So, to change it to 'reported speech', is it:

> You Bi said **she wanted to swim**.

Is the above grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, your change is grammatically correct. "I would like to swim" (我想要游泳) is a polite way of saying "I want to swim" (我要游泳).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression does convey a sense of want, but it can take on several nuances, depending on the context. For example:

> "What do you want to do today?"
>   "I would like to swim."

sounds like a conversation between two friends, trying to schedule the day's activities. However:

> "Did you see Michael Phelps win that race yesterday?"
>   "Yes – I would like to swim like that."

conveys a longing for an ability to swim competitively, not necessarily a desire to go swimming that day.

As Barrie said in his answer, sometimes *I would like to* sounds more polite and less demanding than *I want to*. I also think it's more likely to be used in the realm of the hypothetical, like in the second conversation above. I think if the speaker was talking about concrete plans, instead of hopes and dreams, the expression *I want to* might be more likely to be used:

> "I saw you at the pool yesterday."
>   "Yes, I've been training hard. I want to swim in the state finals next year."

In that case, using *want to* instead of *would like to* shows more resolve and determination.

Although these expressions are almost interchangeable in what they mean fundamentally, the subtle nuances can be complex. Even which word that gets stressed can cause a slight shift in meaning:

For example:

> "I would ***like*** to swim in the finals next year."

seems to convey a different kind of hope than:

> "I ***would*** like to swim in the finals next year."

Getting back to your question, though, there's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence you asked about.

Comment: +1 for exapanding my sketchy answer. There's always a difficulty in answering questions like this, because so much depends on factors beyond the content of the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct:

> “You Bi would like to swim.”
>   = “You Bi wants to swim.”
>   → “You Bi said she wanted to swim.”

You can also use *would* unchanged:

> “I would like to swim.”
>   → “You Bi said she would like to swim.”

Here, you can analyse *would* as conditional—if You Bi went swimming, she would like it. *Would* is also (morphologically) the past form of *will*, so it doesn’t need to change tense for reported speech.

Answer (score 3):

*I would like* and *I want* are different ways of expressing volition. For that reason, it would be inaccurate to report *I would like to swim* as *She said she wanted to swim*. It has to be *She said she would like to swim.*

This use of *would* is sometimes described as having ‘unreal meaning’, but in cases such as this it is perhaps better seen as expressing a degree of tentativeness. The speaker doesn’t want to express her wishes forcefully, and the more polite form *I would like*, as opposed to *I want*, allows her to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 1):

A better choice is to use the verb as it is:

> "You Bi said she would like to swim."